# hide and show upon click in angular

Tags: angular

I have a plus button in angular:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;text-align:left;margin-bottom:2vh;" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="MoreSentences(result.word)">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>More Example Sentences
            </button>
      </div>
```

The code that shows up when button is clicked:

```
<div *ngFor="let results of dictDataSentencesResults">
          <div *ngFor="let each of results.lexicalEntries">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 border_bottom" style="border-bottom:1px solid darkgray;">
              <span style="padding-bottom:2vh;display:inline-block;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;color: #f15a24;text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: 0.8px;">  {{each.lexicalCategory}} </span>
              </div>
              <div *ngFor="let sentences of each.sentences">
                  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 border_bottom">
                      <span style="color:black;font-style:italic;font-weight: normal;padding-bottom:2vh;display:inline-block;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;text-transform:capitalize;"> Phrase:</span>          <span style="padding-bottom:2vh;display:inline-block;font-size:18px;"> ' {{sentences.text}} '</span>
                      </div>
                </div>

              </div>
      </div>
```

Component.ts:

```
  MoreSentences(val) {
    console.log(val);
    this.gotHttpService.getDictonaryDataSentences(val).subscribe(
      data => {

        this.dictDataSentences = data;
        console.log(this.dictDataSentences);
        this.dictDataSentencesResults = data.results;
        console.log(this.dictDataSentencesResults);

      } ,
      error => {
        console.log("some error occured");
        console.log(error.errorMessage);
      }
    );

        }
```

I want the plus icon to be minus when i click on it and show the div and to hide when i click on minus icon.

The page looks like this:
[image]

I have never used toggle feature in angular,so any kind of suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: *ngIf of one property to hide and show this div

Comment: You can use a container to hide/show the content.
`<ng-container *ngIf="show">
//your code that is displayed/hidden here
</ng-container>
<button (click)="show = !show"><button>`
When you click on the button set the "show" variable to "!show".
This works if you have a single button and a single container. Don't forget to initiate the "show" variable to "false" in your component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIf` to hide and show your content based on a flag that's toggled by clicking on the icon. The same flag can be used to set which icon to show.

---

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9pz6kg)